# Qt crashing transferring app to IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, qt, qml

I'm building an app for IOS using Qt, it's not a regular job thingy, so sometimes I keep for a while without any update in the code.
And every time I get back to it I get a new and surprising error.

I was using Qt5.5 (Indie license) and Iphone 5S to build this QML app.

After a couple months without touching the code I came back to it and tried to build and run on my IPhone just to check everything was ok.... was not.

I got the following error:

```
TransferAppSession(05d18047bac1b57a77081395686822ac451a0eee, /<path>/build-XpenseTrackr-iphoneos_clang_Qt_5_6_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphoneos/XpenseTrackr.app)startService on device 05d18047bac1b57a77081395686822ac451a0eee failed, AMDeviceStartService returned 3892314146
TransferAppSession(05d18047bac1b57a77081395686822ac451a0eee, /<path>/build-XpenseTrackr-iphoneos_clang_Qt_5_6_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphoneos/XpenseTrackr.app)Bad file descriptor
```

So I've tried to delete the app from the Iphone, delete the build folder and rebuild it from scratch
Same error.

Then I tried to update my Qt libs to Qt5.6 and Qt Creator to 3.6.1... no success, the same error popup on my face while I try to keep all my hairs on my head.
I'm running on a MacOSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and I don't plan to upgrade soon.

Hey, what about update XCode?

- Open AppStore
- Search for XCode
- Click on Update
- Look for the spinning running forever without anything take effect, no feedback, nothing is happening.
- Repeat

No idea what else I can try and it's really frustrating that every time I need to worry about things not code-related, I really like and enjoy Qt/QML but my plan B is give up it and get something that give less issues and don't debit 20 euros/month from my credit card.

Any suggestion is welcome, even if the suggestion is **"Move to PhoneGap"**.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have bigger problems if you can't even get xcode to update... Try rebooting, logging out of the app store, and logging back in. Also make sure that you can upload an example application from xcode itself and run it on the device.

Comment: The problem with updating XCode can be solved by updating to El Capitan. Mabe you have updated your iOS version on your iPhone and therefore the SDK do not fit anymore.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 7.3 is given as an update option on OSX 10.10 but it's not supported.